# R, ggplot when changing colors/line style: Error in grid.Call.graphics

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some R code to draw a plot. It looks like the image below:

[image]

Now I want to be able to set the line color and style (need it in grey values), add the two straight lines to the legend and remove the title of the legend.

This code works (I put fake data):

```
library(ggplot2)

load ("vns.data")
load ("rw.data")
load("gibbs.data")
```

if you don't load data, do this:

```
vtm1<- c(1,3,4)
vmean<-c(3.9,3.8,3)
vmax<-c(4.1,4.2,4)
vmin<-c(3,2.5,2)
rtm1<- c(1,2,4,5)
rmean<-c(3.9,3.85,3.7,3.1)
rmax<-c(4.1,4.2,4,3.9)
rmin<-c(3,2.5,2,1.9)
gtm1<- c(2,4,5)
gmean<-c(4.1,3.9,3)
gmax<-c(4.1,4,3.9)
gmin<-c(3,2.5,1.5)
vns <- data.frame(vtm1, vmean, vmax, vmin)
gibbs <- data.frame(gtm1, gmean, gmax, gmin)
rw <- data.frame(rtm1, rmean, rmax, rmin)
```

Then continue

```
names(vns) <- c("tm1", "mean", "max", "min")
names(gibbs) <- c("tm1", "mean", "max", "min")
names(rw) <- c("tm1", "mean", "max", "min")
vns$what <- "VNS"
gibbs$what <- "GS"
rw$what <- "RW"


DF <- do.call(rbind, list(vns, gibbs, rw))




plt <- ggplot(DF, aes(x= tm1, ymin= min, ymax= max, y=mean)) +
xlab("Number of TM lookups") + 
ylab("Cross-entropy")+
geom_hline(yintercept=3.2240952381, linetype = "dotted", color="#A8A8A8")+ 
geom_hline(yintercept=3.44366666666667, linetype = "dotted") + 
geom_ribbon(aes(fill=what), alpha=0.3) +  
geom_line(aes(linetype = what))+
theme_bw( )+


 scale_colour_manual(name="what", values=c("vns"="#A8A8A8", "gibbs"="#E8E8E8", "rw"="#C8C8C8")) +  
    scale_fill_manual(name="what", values=c("vns"="#A8A8A8", "gibbs"="#E8E8E8", "rw"="#C8C8C8"))+
    scale_linetype_manual(name="what", values=c("vns"="solid", "gibbs"="dotdash", "rw"="dashed")) 
    print(plt)
```

This code works, when these lines are removed:

```
scale_colour_manual(name="what", values=c("vns"="#A8A8A8", "gibbs"="#E8E8E8", "rw"="#C8C8C8")) +  
scale_fill_manual(name="what", values=c("vns"="#A8A8A8", "gibbs"="#E8E8E8", "rw"="#C8C8C8"))+
scale_linetype_manual(name="what", values=c("vns"="solid", "gibbs"="dotdash", "rw"="dashed"))
```

I get the following error with my real data. With the toy data, it works fine.

```
Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_lines, x$x, x$y, index, x$arrow) : 
  invalid line type
```

With the toy data, it works fine. Yet, the horizontal lines need to be added to the legend, and the legend name removed. Therefore, I have made my real data available here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13564139/vns.saved and https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13564139/rw.saved and https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13564139/gibbs.saved

Any idea what can cause this error, and why only with the real data, not the toy data? I have already rebooted as suggested in some other posts here.

[image]

Comment: Could you include your complete `ggplot` code?

Comment: This is the complete code. I might rearrange it, so that the three lines are inline with the rest. I hope it is clear for you now.

Comment: I still don't see complete `ggplot`-code. This normally starts with something like `ggplot(data=vns, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line() + scale_fill_manual()`. At this moment I only some `scale` code.

Comment: Yes, ggplot( is about on line 25, I also added the data preparation I did, which is relevant for the color references.

Comment: I also already checked for NA values, there are none: ny(is.na(vns))
[1] FALSE
> any(is.na(gibbs))
[1] FALSE
> any(is.na(rw))
[1] FALSE

Comment: It would have been clearer if you had the toy data creation and the real data processing separated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your toy data, the `what` column has values `"vns"`, `"gibbs"`, and `"rw"`. In your real data, it is `"VNS"`, `"GS"`, and `"RW"`. The mappings you have in the `scale_*` calls work for the toy data, but fail for the real data because the names are not the same. You would need

```
scale_linetype_manual(name="what", values=c("VNS"="solid", "GS"="dotdash", "RW"="dashed"))
```

etc.

Linetype was the one to throw an error because colour and fill could both handle the value being missing (which it was since it was not mapped to something), but a linetype of missing is an error.

Comment: OMG! You solved it. I have been looking at this for four hours already... Makes total sense. Any idea on how to remove the title from the legend?

Comment: Also, you do not need to put the names in quotes. `values=c(VNS="solid", GS="dotdash", RW="dashed")` works fine.

Comment: ah, super, you made my evening! ps, theme(legend.title=element_blank()) works for the legend title.